# spRbind SpatialPolygonDataFrames with different fields

Tags: r, spatial, rbind

I'm trying to append two SpatialPolygonDataFrames that have different fields. I've been using spRbind and have created unique row ids for each data frame using spChFIDs. But I still get the following error.

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

An example is block-level shapefile date from NHGIS for the states of Missouri and Illinois. Missouri has 17 fields and Illinois has 18.

Missouri:
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "../nhgis0030_shapefile_tl2010_290_block_2010", layer: "MO_block_2010"
with 343565 features
It has 17 fields

Illinois:
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "../nhgis0030_shapefile_tl2010_170_block_2010", layer: "IL_block_2010"
with 451426 features
It has 18 fields
Integer64 fields read as strings:  ALAND10 AWATER10

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bind` method from the `raster` package for this

As always, first set up some example data (you should have include some in your question):

```
library(raster)
# example data
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
p
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 12 
#extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#variables   : 5
#names       : ID_1,     NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA 
#min values  :    1,   Diekirch,    1, Capellen,   76 
#max values  :    3, Luxembourg,    9,    Wiltz,  312 

p1 <- p[p$NAME_2=='Mersch', ]
p2 <- p[p$NAME_2=='Diekirch', ]
p3 <- p[p$NAME_2=='Remich', ]

# remove all fields for p1
p1 <- as(p1, 'SpatialPolygons')
# remove one field for p3
p3$NAME_1 <- NULL
# add a new field
p3$newfield <- 25
```

Now we have the example data, use `bind` to combine the three SpatialPolygon* objects:

```
x <- bind(p1, p2, p3)

data.frame(x)
#  ID_1   NAME_1 ID_2   NAME_2 AREA newfield
#1   NA     <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA       NA
#2    1 Diekirch    2 Diekirch  218       NA
#3    2     <NA>    7   Remich  129       25
```